# Android Intent to Force Binary File Download

Tags: android, android-intent

In web server configuration we usually force file downloads by setting the MIME type to `application/octet-stream`.

I have an app which parses a directory listing from a web server where all files are downloadable. The expected action when a user click on a file is that the user is prompted to select a method to download it.

For URIs which refer to `http://webserver/foo.mkv`, `ADM` is not offered as one which supports downloading it. Instead, Chrome or Browser is offered. However, if I choose Chrome, it loads the address and decides it can't render it and then offers `ADM`.

My question is, how is Chrome ensuring that `ADM` is an app that can handle my download intent, such that I can have that offered as a suitable app in the first place?

Here is my Intent creation code:

```
URL downloadUrl = new URL(MainActivity.this.listingUrl, entry.getPath());
Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(downloadUrl.toString());
Intent downloadIntent = new Intent();
downloadIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
downloadIntent.setType("application/octet-stream");
downloadIntent.setData(downloadUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(downloadIntent, "Pick download manager..."));
```

where `downloadUri` is something like: `http://webserver/foo.mkv`.

Comment: Any special reason to let the user select the app to download and not calling the `DownloadManager` directly?

Comment: What is the "ADM" that you refer to?

Comment: @tato.rodrigo In order to support any user installed download managers, such as Advanced Download Manager, i.e. the ADM I refer to. I have tried many combinations of Intent properties now but none seem to always include ADM for all Uris, but all offer Google Chrome which then offers ADM and another custom download manager (Loader). How does the Google Chrome app call these? The answer to that question would answer this question. I have reverse engineered the ADM manifest, can I legally provided a link to this?